# How to use final resolved applicationId in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-flavors

Say I have the following build.gradle

```
android{
    defaultConfig{
        applicationId "com.example.base"
    }
    buildTypes{
        release{
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug{
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    productFlavors{
        free{
            applicationId "com.example.free"
        }
        paid{
            applicationId "com.example.paid"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add the resulting application id to strings.xml, like this:

```
resValue "string", "app_package", applicationId
```

So I can then use this value in intents `targetPackage` defined in preferences xml

But the value changes depending on what block I put that line in:

- defaultConfig -> "com.example.base" (always the base Id, useless)
- productFlavours.free -> "com.example.free" (problem is this **does not change** to "com.example.free.dev" for debug builds)
- productFlavours -> Error, does not build
- buildTypes.debug -> Error, does not build

By using the applicationIdSuffix, I need gradle to resolve the final id before I can use it. How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this after [`productFlavors`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html) within [`android`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/) DSL:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue  "string", "app_package", variant.applicationId
}
```

In `freeDebug` build this will be added in `app/intermediates/res/merged/free/debug/values/values.xml`:

```
<string name="app_package" translatable="false">com.example.free.dev</string>
```

In `paidDebug`:

```
<string name="app_package" translatable="false">com.example.paid.dev</string>
```